# Why did Ken steal and then throw away batteries (end of S2E2)

Tags: plot-explanation, succession

At the end of *Succession* season 2 episode 2, Kendall goes to a small store and steals a pack of batteries that he throws away immediately after leaving the shop.

In my opinion, this is an act of rebellion against "the authority" (his father), after Ken

> reluctantly executed his father's Vaulter plan.

Can this be something else?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, and not sure why you got one, maybe because you try to answer the question inside the question itself, try to remove the "in my opinion part". Otherwise, not something to worry about, question open and can still get answers. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron At least if there was a clear reason the question could be improved... some people here, on this site especially, downvote faster than their own shadow without any explanation. When the reason is not obvious, a comment is welcome.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not personal, and just part of Stack Exchange. No good ever comes from trying to figure reason for downvotes, and I say this from experience of 10+ years. So all good, the question is fine, and hope you'll keep posting. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron I've also been on SE (esp SO) for some time. Being downvoted for no reason (we can always find reasons, but here it's not obvious, and, in doubt, don't dv!) doesn't encourage people to post. Look, only 5 questions in the last 24h,  and M&TV has been alive for 10+ years...

Comment: Well about only 5 questions, the site moderators killed the activity when banning identification questions. They were the most popular, often reaching HNQ, bringing lots of traffic. Their reasoning might be good, to keep high quality, but is it worth the price? Dunno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is revealed in S02 E04: Kendall has a new addiction: cleptomania (he steals some random stuff) and they (Gerri, Colin...) try to keep it under the rag, but Gerri admits it to Shiv.

Answer (score 4):

As you remember, Kendall is broken after Season 1 finale. He wanted to gain some kind of control and power in his life.

> i think it was a display of kendall feeling absolutely powerless. he
> didn’t want to shut down vaulter, he did it “because his dad told him
> to.” he’s firmly under his dad’s thumb and hates it. he stole the
> batteries so he could feel some semblance of control in his life
> again, some modicum of power, however small.
>
> [reddit comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/SuccessionTV/comments/csalpv/comment/exdneti/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), u/justsomehandsomeguy

Comment: It looks like you have picked it from Reddit. Please note it is not really a credible source. However, if you are adding an excerpt from somewhere, please mention the source.

Comment: Are you quoting your own Reddit post?

Comment: @EleventhDoctor no it's not mine. I checked about quoting from external sources. However i added the full link and will be aware of Reddit sources next time. Also it should be noted the question does not really have a definitive answer.